# Bind JSON with table in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

how can i bind my json object with knockoutjs, here is my json :

```
 "{\"Sport\":[{\"Name\":\"nana\",\"Description\":\"lmkmsdqd\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-07-22T00:00:00\"},
              {\"Name\":\"sfqsdffqf\",\"Description\":\"lkqjskdlqsd\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-07-22T00:00:00\"}],
    \"Music\":[{\,\"Name\":\"nana\",\"Description\":\"lmkmsdqd\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-07-22T00:00:00\"},
               {\"Name\":\"sfqsdffqf\",\"Description\":\"lkqjskdlqsd\",\"EndDate\":\"2012-07-22T00:00:00\"}]}"
```

please suggest how can i bind it !!

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Where did all the slashes come from? There is also a hanging comma at the beginning of the music section.

Comment: the slashes come from JSON.NET , i have convert my object ike this : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.BuzzCompaignByInterest);

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087253/why-is-json-net-adding-all-these-backslashes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, so I put together a crude [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/re6fv/) to demonstrate some binding concepts, as well as ViewModel construction. I had to clean up your JSON to do it. It demonstrates template, foreach, and text binding. If you haven't already done so, I highly recommend going through the [tutorials on the knockout site](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Here are the HTML bindings:

```
Sports
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'listingTemplate', foreach: sports}"></ul>
</br>
Music
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'listingTemplate', foreach: music}"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="listingTemplate">
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span></br>
    <span data-bind="text: description"></span></br>
    <span data-bind="text: endDate"></span></br></br>
</li>
</script>​
```

and the viewmodels:

```
var Listing = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.Name || '');
    this.description = ko.observable(data.Description|| '');
    this.endDate = ko.observable(data.EndDate|| '');
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    this.sports = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Sport, function(i) {return new Listing(i);})
    );
    this.music = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Music, function(i) {return new Listing(i);})
    );
};
```